# Subtracting from LPVOID

Tags: c++

Not very prof. with C++. The code I've been working on is : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175819(v=vs.85).aspx

My problem resides in this area :

```
_tprintf(TEXT("  Data portion begins at: %#p\n  Size: %d bytes\n") \
             TEXT("  Overhead: %d bytes\n  Region index: %d\n\n"),
             Entry.lpData,
             Entry.cbData,
             Entry.cbOverhead,
             Entry.iRegionIndex);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, The **Entry.lpData** is the address of data portion of heap block. I want to read 8 byte before **Entry.lpData** address. So when I'm simply subtracting 8 from Entry.lpData and trying to read bytes, I'm getting the error

```
hexDump(entry.lpData - 8, 8);


heapwalk.cpp(119): error C2036: 'PVOID' : unknown size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to `void` are pointers to *anything*, so it makes no sense to perform pointer arithmetic on them directly.  In this case, since you know you need an 8 byte offset, you will simply cast it to a `char*` first.  In the general case you would know what sort of data it actually points to and cast it to a pointer of that type.

```
char *p = static_cast<char*>(entry.lpData) - 8;
```

This works because `char*` is an exception to [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  Don't try this with arbitrary types.

Comment: Something like this -> unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)address; ?

Comment: @DavidA., C++ casts are better and `char*` is fine. `static_cast<char*>(lpData) - 8`. Note that 8 is a magic number that should be replaced with something that explains what the 8 actually does.

Comment: @DavidA.: I added an example